# Dynamic data in Highcharts geomaps

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

I am trying to call API to show data in `chartOptions`. but in `data` I am unable to pass it by `this.letsTry` I don't know where I am getting wrong.

[**data-local.component.html**]

```
<highcharts-chart id="container" [Highcharts]="Highcharts" [constructorType]="chartConstructor" [options]="chartOptions" style="width: 100%; height: 550px; display: block;">
</highcharts-chart>
```

[**data-local.component.ts file**]

```
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DatalocalService } from 'src/app/services/datalocal.service';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts/highmaps';
import MapModule from 'highcharts/modules/map';
declare var require: any
const mapWorld = require('@highcharts/map-collection/custom/world.geo.json')
MapModule(Highcharts);
@Component({
  selector: 'app-data-local',
  templateUrl: './data-local.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data-local.component.scss']
})
export class DataLocalComponent implements OnInit {

  skipCountryVal: boolean = false;
  letsTry = [];
  constructor(
    private commonService: CommonService,
    private local: DatalocalService
  ) { }
 
  ngOnInit(): void {
    let args1 = {
      'body': `query {
        DataLocal(skip: ${this.skipCountryVal ? 1 : 0}, first: 10) {
          Count
          Code
        }
      }
    `
    };
    this.DataLocal(args1);
  }

  Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
  chartConstructor = "mapChart";
  chartData = [{ code3: "ABW", z: 105 }, { code3: "AFG", z: 35530 }];

  chartOptions: Highcharts.Options = {
    chart: {
      map: mapWorld
    },
    title: {
      text: "Data local report"
    },
    subtitle: { 
      text:
        // 'Source map: <a href="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js">World, Miller projection, medium resolution</a>'
        ''
    },
    mapNavigation: {
      enabled: true,
      buttonOptions: {
        alignTo: "spacingBox"
      }
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: true
    },
    colorAxis: {
      min: 0
    },
    series: [
      {
        type: "map",
        name: "Random data",
        states: {
          hover: {
            color: "#24e9ad"
          }
        },
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          format: "{point.name}"
        },
        allAreas: true,
        data: this.letsTry
      }
    ]
  };

  // data localization api
  DataLocal(args1) {
    this.localService.DataLocal(args1).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        let tempGeoData = [];
        let apiGeoData = data['data']['DataLocal'];
        for (let i = 0; i < apiGeoData.length; i++) {
          tempGeoData.push(
            [
              data['data']['DataLocal'][i]['Code'],
              data['data']['DataLocal'][i]['Count']
            ]
            
          )
          // this.chartOptions.data[i] = tempGeoData[i];
          this.letsTry = tempGeoData;
        }
        console.log('Data from API', this.letsTry);
      }
    )
  }
}
```

[**sample data from API**]

```
{
  "data": {
    "DataLocal": [
      {
        "CodeCount": 1998,
        "Code": "au"
      },
      {
        "CodeCount": 7422,
        "Code": "fr"
      },
      {
        "CodeCount": 3062,
        "Code": "in"
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in your code

1. Initial HighCharts after letsTry has data
2. You are assigning letsTry inside for loop. It should outside

Initialize `chartoption` after DataLocal completes and letsTry is updated with values.

```
// data localization api
DataLocal(args1) {
  return this.localService.DataLocal(args1).subscribe( // <-- return this promise so you can use it .then() 
    (data) => {
      let tempGeoData = [];
      let apiGeoData = data['data']['DataLocal'];
      for (let i = 0; i < apiGeoData.length; i++) {
        tempGeoData.push(
          [
            data['data']['DataLocal'][i]['Code'],
            data['data']['DataLocal'][i]['Count']
          ]
        );
      }

      this.letsTry = tempGeoData; // <-- moved out 

      console.log('Data from API', this.letsTry);

      return "success";
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: @samruddhi-dhaygude you should mark one of the reply as answer if it resolved your issue or helped to resolve. This will encourage others to answer post